# ngTable how to set filter-data for a table data cell programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngtable

I'm using ngTable and async loading the table, but one of the columns is using a select filter, and when it is invoked the table data hasn't resolved yet.  Originally I was testing ngTable using a local JSON object and this worked, but now I'm not sure how to populate the select.  Is it possible to programmatically set the column's filter-data to populate the select field?

ngTable Cell

```
<td data-title="'Status'" 
    sortable="'status'" 
    filter="{ 'status': 'select' }"
    filter-data="getStatus()"  // hasn't resolved yet and select is empty
    ng-bind="doc.status"></td>
```

Controller Function

```
$scope.getStatus = function() {

    var def = $q.defer();
    var arr = [];
    var status = [];

    // NOTE: RestService.getPackages() below isn't resolved and select is empty

    angular.forEach( RestService.getPackages(), function( item ) {

        // Check if status already exists
        if( arr.indexOf( item.status ) === -1 ) {

            // Store status for comparison to avoid duplicates
            arr.push( item.status );

            // Store status information for filtering
            status.push({
                'id': item.status,
                'title': item.status
            });
        }
    });

    def.resolve( status );

    return def;
};
```

Comment: could you reproduce bug in plunk, with using of timer to simulate network latency?

Comment: are you using `angular promises` or  `q promises`? and `RestService.getPackages()` return promise ,isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in `promise` chaining due to the invocation of `RestService.getPackages()`,you should do it more explicitly by callback,here my little example:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
    var def = $q.defer();
    var Names = [];

    //simulate  network delay
    $timeout(function(){

      Names.push({
         title: "Enos",
        id: "Enos"});
      Names.push({
         title: "Nephi",
        id: "Nephi"});

    }, 1000);

    def.resolve(Names);
    return def;
  };
```

and here working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/629aax3TsMYbVBHO141F?p=preview).